# array component with string keys

Tags: delphi, arrays, string, key

About two years ago I have found a component that can be used to create array with string keys on delphi... anyone know a component like this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the component: http://www.explainth.at/en/delphi/daa.shtml

Answer (score 3):

In Delphi 2010 (I think 2009 as well) there is a generic TDictionary class in Generics.Collections.pas you could use.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for a HashMap. The [Delphi Container Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dclx/) provides one.